# testing a function

Tags: testing

I have setup a file called mymodule.test and in the module I have file called mymodule.inc.
Every is working but I am unsure about the following. Below is mymodule.test file.

```
class MyModule extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  public static function getInfo() {
    return array (
      'name' => t('my module'),
      'description' => t('my module.'),
      'group' => t('My module'),
    );
  }
  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp('mymodule');
  }
}
```

Inside mymodule.inc I have the following function

```
function mydisplay(){ returns "This is true" }
```

How I do I tell tests class I want to do an test assertion of true or false on the mydisplay function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a method whose names start with test, for example `testMyDisplay()`, where you test the value returned from the function.

```
public testMyDisplay() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule');
  $this->assertEqual($expected_result, mydisplay());
}
```

Clearly, this code is valid if the function is not a form builder; otherwise, the code needs to be different. Since you used `DrupalWebTestCase` as base class, and not `DrupalTestCase`, I guess you need to do more than just checking the result returned from a function, or that function is not simply a function that returns a string.